# Coniditional execution of the form by php

Tags: php, forms, validation

I would like to conditionally execute the form.

I mean, *"if something"* then the code will be written like this and will be executed `<form action="aaaa.php">`. *"Else"*, there will be `<form action="bbb.php">`, which will be again executed.

Execution and, of course, validation (or rewriting the `action=""`) will be done automatically when the user press the send button.

Is it possible to do it by PHP?

Would anyone know how to make this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Try with -

```
<form action="<?php echo (something) ? 'aaaa.php' : 'bbb.php';?>" >
```

[Check Here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can code like this

```
<?php

if(true) {  // your condition in true's  place
?>
    if true your html code here
like <form action="aa.html"></form>
<?php
} else {
?>
    else your html code here
like <form action="bb.html"></form>
<?php 
}
?>
```